# Java regex extract key-value without quotes

Tags: java, regex

I have a list of key-values as such:-

```
{
  "xxx" : "1234",
  "yyy" : "1234",
  "zzz" : "1234"
}
```

I have a regex pattern:-

```
String pattern = ".*zzz\\s*:\\s*(.*)[\n\r]";
```

that only extracts values in case of a match when key is 'zzz'.

However I don't get a match due to the quotes...how can I altern my pattern to get the match? Also, I don't want to get quotes in my value either.

Comment: Looks like you should use a json library instead of regex here..

Comment: no..because there are other things below and json parser wont work with that

Comment: If there are other things below, make sure whichever regex you use doesn't pick up things from there. I also really recommend using some sort of parser over regex if possible but of course I do not know your full situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get the match due to the missing double quote after the `zzz`.

```
String pattern = ".*zzz\"\\s*:\\s*(.*)[\n\r]";
                        ^--- Here
```

Btw, You can use:

```
String pattern = ".*zzz\".*?\"(.*?)\"";
```

Then you have to grab the content from the capturing group through the Matcher `match(1)`.

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vX8cQ0/1)**

**[IDE One demo](https://ideone.com/gjj4BC)**

Comment: yea but I only want the value, not the key-value pair

Comment: @Philo, the regex is fine, you are talking about grabbing what you captured in your capture group. You will have to access by the Matcher method `group(1)`

Comment: ahh snap.. I was using group(0)

Comment: @Philo, `group(0)` contains the full match where the positive numbers contain what the capturing groups captured. Btw, have updated the answer with a IDE One code

Comment: ".*zzz\"\\s*:\\s*(.*)[\n\r]" didnt work for me... but this did ".*zzz\".*?\"(.*)"

Comment: one issue though... it is picking up the trailing " (quotes)

Comment: @Philo, check you don't have a typo in your regex, it's working well. Check it here https://regex101.com/r/vX8cQ0/1

Comment: @Philo, you were correct I had the typo lol. Check the working java code https://ideone.com/gjj4BC

Comment: Voila! thanks. now its working as it should.. I gotta go back and check what I was doing wrong. lol